# HTML anchor tag in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, browser

I have this weird issue in chrome (only in chrome).

I have a page with std layout (header,content,footer with left and right margin). Content section has an iframe containing many anchor tags of the form `<a href="#" onclick="doSomething()">Text</a>`

When any of this anchor tag is clicked, header goes hidden. Any anchor tag of the same form but outside the iframe works fine.

I have verified that the DOM has the header elements intact. Display is not 'none' (Zooming in the page to 150%, header starts appearing slightly).

When I force the browser to redraw the page, like changing any css attribute(height) of the content section , header appears.

**When I change the href from '#' to say '#nonexistent', the link works perfectly fine.**

One quick fix is to change the href to, say `javascript:void(null);` (and this works too) or something equivalent. But I'm somehow constrained that I can't add any scriptlets.
This looks so weird. Can somebody help/point me to the right direction?

Comment: Is this the header inside the iframe, or the header of the parent page? Also, the way it's written now the page does `doSomething` first and then goes to `#`. Is that by design?

Comment: Do you have to use anchors? Can you instead of `<a href="#" onclick="doSomething()">Text</a>` use something simple like `<span onclick="doSomething()">Text</span>` ? You can style the span to look like an anchor if needed

Comment: the thing is , there is nothing I can do to the way these links are constructed. So, span may work but I can't . As I said earlier even href=#soemthing (something doesn'e exist) works fine. I'm just trying to understand why this happens

Answer (score 0):

Try changing/adding a target attribute to the anchor tags in the iframe. I'm not certain whether the header is disappearing within the iframe or the parent page, but my guess is you want target="_parent".

Also, javascript:void(null) should be javascript:void. void is a type, not a function. Calling (null) is unnecessary.